# Issue reloading cellForRowAtIndexPath calling from a method in another class - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following method within a `ViewController` class:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:

    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSInteger tag = cell.tag;
        // SEND TO SINGLE NEWS FEED TO DISPLAY THE INFORMATION OF THE VIDEO
        singleNewsFeed* myScript = [[singleNewsFeed alloc] init];
        [myScript startProcess:tag];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moveToSingleData" sender:self];
    }
```

The receiver class:

```
- (void)startProcess:(NSInteger)number {
    NSInteger check = number;
    singlecellID = check;
    // MAKE REQuEST TO SERVER
    [self makeRequests];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

So what happens is that `makeRequests` runs and the `tableView` is refreshed.  All methods for the `tableView` run except the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Here is the thing I know that all of these work properly because I have the same exact classes doing the same exact thing except they are `sub viewcontrollers` of a `parent viewcontroller`.  I had the same exact issue and used `self.parentViewController.childViewControllers[1];` to fix that when calling the method and it worked perfect.  But this is different because this is a completely separate `ViewController`.  So therefore I am not sure what to use to call that `ViewController` that allows `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to work correctly.

Suggestions, thoughts?

David

Comment: When you say "All methods for the tableView run except..." which ones specifically.  What values are you returning for number of sections and number of rows?

Comment: It looks like your problem is that you're calling startProcess on an instance of singleNewsFeed that you create with alloc init, instead of the one that is created by the segue.

Comment: @phillipmills `numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection heightForRowAtIndexPath` all run.

Comment: And the values being returned from the number* ones...?

Comment: @phillipmills what do you mean?

Comment: @phillipmills in the `numberOfRowsInSection` It seems to process 3 times and outputs, `0 0 1`.

Comment: So either you're telling it you have 3 sections and two of them have no rows (the other has 1 row) or perhaps you have multiple copies of the view controller.  (When you have no rows, it's not going to ask for cells.)

Comment: Well here is the thing the `makeRequest` method is only running once.

Comment: And that is setting an `array` that the `numberOfRowsInSection` gets the count of that array.  It should always be 1.

Comment: Look at the value of `self` (NSLog or debugger) inside `numberOfRowsInSection` each time it gets called.  If you don't have 3 sections, I'm suspicious that you are dealing with different objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` but I don't think object you're calling it from is your table view controller. No?